# Special RegEx Patterns

Tags: regex

I am trying to search for a specific pattern using regex, but I am having a difficult time. I have over 4,000 images, named as three different file sets, named like so...

- 0001234_name-of-file.jpeg
- 0001235_name-of-file_100.jpeg
- 0001236_name-of-file_200.jpeg

What I want to do is JUST search for the files like 0001234_name-of-file.jpeg

I do NOT want any of the files that have the _100 or _200 at the end before the extension.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What tool/language/OS do you use to do that?

Comment: I am using PowerGrep for Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I would go with that :

`^((?!_[21]00).)*$`

Which matches strings which do not contain either `_100` or `_200`

Comment: What if the file name contains `_100`?